# How to update email value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We know that laravel has an update () method that updates records using the http "put" method. But I do not know how to create an edpoint in which I will be able to modify the email.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'name' => 'Abigail',
            'state' => 'CA'
        ]);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->get("name");
        $user->email = $request->get("email");
        $user->password = $request->get("password");
        $user->save();
        return response()->json($user->toArray(), 200);
    }



    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And my route:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('v1/users/create', 'UserController@store');
```

RESTful APIs made by me tests in Postman. Help me somebody

Comment: All API I have built has always required my own custom controller/methods to create users. You can use laravel's passport mechanism but It also requires your own custom controller. https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: Why don't you use the `$fillable` property on your models, so that you can simply hydrate your models all at once from the `$request` object. E.g. `$user->update($request->all());`. Then it doesn't matter if you send one property or all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I think you need to create a route to link to update method in your controller same way you created a post for creating `user`.

```
Route::put('v1/users/client/{id}', 'UserController@update);
```

OR you can use laravel predefined code to create all CRUD routes.

```
Route::resource('v1/users/client', 'UserController').
```

To view all the routes created, use

```
php artisan route:list
```

Have a further study on [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Yes you are right. I know what the route will look like but I do not know what the code should look like in the update method to change the email

Comment: You need to retrieve `User` first from your database. You can use eloquent or simple query to do it. You can find more on writing queries [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)